# The Museum of Deleted Answers

Tags: discussion

I'm suggesting we keep a repository of answers deleted for good and sufficient reason, but the loss of which would be a shame.  I'm prompted to this request by the following answer to the featured question about the etymology of *shenanigans*:

> It's clearly from the Mandarin Chinese. 'She na ni gan' ...roughly
>   translates as: One way or another, sooner or later, I'm going to get
>   your monies, your lands, & your women, you stupid white schmucks."

Don't get me wrong, this needs to go, but I'm still laughing trying to figure which pictograms capture all the Yiddish nuance of "schmuck."  Also to the claim of a "rough translation."  While this lampoons our (sometimes too serious) view of the site, it also makes fun of folk etymology.  I've chosen to interpret the comments as ironic (or at least two out of three), which makes this even better.

Comment: Stack Exchange already has a mechanism for archiving clever, chuckle-evoking witticisms. They are called [upvoted comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267989/word-phrase-allusion-for-spreading-false-intel-to-catch-a-mole#comment590479_267989), and are often accompanied by smirking emoticons.

Comment: @J.R. What I don't want to lose is the bad answer.  In any case comments, up- or down-voted, disappear with the deleted answer as well.  Your link takes me to an answer about "disinformation."  What am I missing?

Comment: What are you missing? Inaccurate contributions that merely lampoon the site and poke fun at folk etymology are better left as amusing comments, rather than so-called answers. That's all I was trying to say.

Comment: @J.R. I don't think I'm the one missing anything here.  I want the inaccurate contributions removed to one place where they're clearly marked as only "so-called" answers and can't mislead anyone.  "Amusing" comments are scattered and shouldn't be left if they might trip up the unwary. I wouldn't want anything saved that poked fun at folks personally, but I think folk etymology is fair game.  But maybe you're right:  God forbid we save anything that lampoons the site.

Comment: @deadrat - If I understand what you're wanting, that's not an ELU issue. That would be a redesign of the Stack Exchange. Sounds like you should ask for a feature request on [meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/). In any case, my original comment was meant to be tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Link is http://english.stackexchange.com/a/294531/4972

Comment: The system already deals with this well. People downvote it or upvote it. a mod can delete it and or convert it to a comment. There's lots more things that'd be desirable for the site than a secondary list of deleted but 'likeable' (?) answers. If you like it enough, favorite the question or save it somehow yourself.

Comment: @J.R. This hardly seems likely.  Perhaps a tag is all that's necessary.

Comment: @Mitch The system doesn't deal with this at all.  This isn't a matter of upvoting, downvoting, or deleting, all of which work just like they're supposed to.  And if I'm the only one who thinks this and posts like it are amusing and worth saving, then so be it.

Answer (score 3):

Deleted answers are already viewable by anyone with sufficient reputation.

Yes, you'd have to go through whatever process you use now to find answers that are interesting or informative, although you'd be looking specifically for deleted posts. Mods can do that; I don't know if regular users can or not.

I don't think putting deleted answers that you personally find sufficiently amusing to preserve them in a Meta post is particularly useful for future visitors, although I believe someone on SO has a personal blog of screenshots of favorite deleted things and possibly some funny situations encountered in review queues. You could probably do that if you were so inclined.

Comment: Of course, but this is hardly a sufficient answer.  How can I know about these the answers that are worthy of preservation?  Should I just go through all the deleted answers?  Is there even a way to do that?  And how did this answer get a checkmark?  I certainly didn't accept it.

Comment: @deadrat The checkmark is probably not actually checked. They darkened the outline a bit because people with maladjusted contrast could not see it.

Comment: You're right.  Thank you.  I clicked and unclicked the checkmark.  And I think the difference is that the accepted mark is green, but to my own maladjusted vision, the difference is barely discernible.  Once again, it's just me.  Never mind.